# FileChannel vs RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, io, nio

Considering that FileChannel in Java 7 implements the interface SeekableByteChannel. Is there any use in using RandomAccessFile rather than FileChannel?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally I've always found the nio APIs hard to understand and work with... whereas the `RandomAccessFile` API is more familiarly stream-like. That's just a matter of opinion of course, which is why I haven't added it as an answer. This feels like a pretty subjective question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`RadomAccessFile` and `FileChannel` are completely different things.
`RandomAccessFile` was introduced to java ages ago before NIO (e.g. channels). It is useful to operate with files when you have to read and write at specified location of file (not sequentially).
However the read and write operations are blocked, e.g. if you call read method it is blocked until the bytes are read.

Channels belong to so called non-blocking IO that allows read (and write) bytes without being blocked. The only relation between `RandomAccessFile` and `FileChannel` is that you can get access to channel through random access file.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "However the read and write operations are blocked, e.g. if you call read method it is blocked until the bytes are read." ? Could you provide me another real life example?

Comment: -1 FileChannel is blocking, too. It's just an interface for random file and the usage of a ByteBuffer instead of byte[], but both block as hell.

Comment: AlexR, you must be thinking about `AsynchronousFileChannel`, which technically speaking is "asynchronous" as opposed to the non-blocking mode you can get from socket channels and pipes using a `Selector`.

Comment: @MartinAndersson, 10x for clarification. I really do not remember exactly what did I mean when wrote this answer 3.5 years ago.

Comment: If this is not the answer(as I see -ve votes), then what is the correct answer?